# Finding out if a Linked List has a Cycle [Code Wars Problem]

Tags: c++

```
bool hasCycle(Node * head)
{
  Node *p = NULL;
  Node *q = head;
  
  while(q)
  {
    q = q->next;
    if(q->next != NULL) q = q->next;
    p = p->next;
  }
  return p == q ? true : false;
}
```

My code works for most of the solutions, but it fails one test case for some reason. Can someone take a look at my code and explain to me what is wrong with my logic. Heres the link to the Code Wars https://www.codewars.com/kata/5af9a4b2de4c7fdab30000e5/train/cpp

Comment: i dont understand how `p = p->next;` can pass any test case. `p` is `NULL` and never anything else in your code

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Tip: Don't cast a boolean to a boolean. Here, just `return p == q` is sufficient. The rest is just clutter.

Comment: This code doesn't work. It doesn't test for loops. It's got the elements you should see in such a solution, but they are really jumbled up.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yeah that makes sense since I can't go next anywhere because my P is null and I should set it on head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind this problem is to use two pointers: a *fast* one and a *slow* one. If there is a loop, the `fast` will catch up with the `slow`. If there is no loop, the `fast` will reach the end first.

Your code didn't exihibit the logic like this. I don't know what you are trying to do. Here is my code:

```cpp
bool hasCycle(Node * head)
{
  Node *fast = head, *slow = head;
  while (fast && fast->next) {
    fast = fast->next->next;
    slow = slow->next;
    if (fast == slow) return true; // here the fast catches the slow
  }
  return false; // here the fast reaches the end of the linked list
}
```

Comment: ah okay I got it.